# Passing JQuery arrays to Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x, javascript-objects

I have 5 arrays, that are created in JQuery: soups[], salads[], entrees[], main_c[], desserts[]

I need to pass those arrays as an array of arrays to python code to calculate Cartesian Product ([Get the cartesian product of a series of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists))

What is the way to do it?

Comment: Do these pieces of code have a client/server relationship? Are they running in the same device?

Comment: @SamH. arrays are dynamically built in the front from the selected checkboxes. Python code is in the back.

Comment: Are you using Django? Flask?

Comment: @SamH. running on Flask

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/jquery/#